# Kill first command as soon as second exits

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I've been looking for best practice for this scenario for a long time.

If I have process2 that depends on process1 running beforehand. I set up an alias like:

```
alias both='process1 & process2'
```

Then, when process2 exits, I would like for process1 to exit as well (my current solution is to go back to the terminal and `kill %%`).

For example (to connect to an iOS device from mac over usb):

```
alias usbssh='/usr/local/bin/iproxy 2222 22 & ssh -p 2222 root@localhost'
```

How do I keep `iproxy` running, and kill it as soon as `ssh` exits?

Comment: Just seperately, do you have more info, re: Connecting to iOS over USB, via SSH?

Comment: @tjt263 - obviously only works for jailbroken devices...

Comment: @tjt263, I really don't get what you are asking me. Can you please say explicitly what info you are after?

Comment: Don't think I can make it much simpler than that.. I've never heard of `iproxy` or `ssh` over USB and I'm just curious. I don't even really know enough about it to be more specific.

Comment: Ok. `iproxy` is a utility to port forward local port to a port on an apple mobile device connected via usb. It is a part of the open source `libimobiledevice` project. In the exaple above, `localhost:2222` is forwarded to port 22 on the connected iphone. The iPhone has an `ssh` daemon listening on port 22. Anything else you want me to expand on?

Comment: See https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libusbmuxd/blob/master/tools/iproxy.c and http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/SSH_Over_USB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just append `kill $!` to the end: `process1 & process2; kill $!`

`$!` is a variable (confusingly known as a "parameter" in Bash), and will [**expand**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) to the last background PID anywhere:

> Expands to the process ID of the job most recently placed into the background, whether executed as an asynchronous command or using the bg builtin (see JOB CONTROL below).

`%%` is special, and will only expand to the last background PID in the context of shell built-in commands like `fg` and `kill`. Unfortunately this isn't clear from the `man` page:

> The symbols %% and %+ refer to the shell's notion of the current job, which is the last job stopped while it was in  the  foreground  or  started in the background.

---

PS: If you need to make this a command string, make sure `kill $!` is single-quoted so it's expanded at runtime. Even better, write a function instead of an alias to avoid their [limitations](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Aliases).

Comment: Great! actually, it is much easier then I thought... BTW, can you explain `$!` vs `%%`?

Comment: Excellent; I agree, re: function>alias.